# Counting in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, count

This my query

```
Select articles.id,articles.userid,articles.article,count(articles_likes.id), count(article_dislikes.id) 
from articles
Left join article_likes 
on article_likes.article_id=articles.id 
Left join article_dislikes 
on article_dislikes.article_id=articles.id 
group by articles.id ;
```

I want to count the number of rows in article_likes table and article_dislikes table im getting the value correct upto 2 rows. When there is a third and so on entries. I'm getting wrong counting of rows.
I don't know where the problem is. I think I may be getting wrong values because I'm using the same table for two times.

I have three tables

1)articles contains id,userid and article
2)Articles_likes table contains-like_id ,user_id and article_id
3)Articles_dislikes table contains dislike_id ,user_id and article_id

Comment: Not "join then count", but "count in subquery then join". As a palliative - `COUNT(DISTINCT tableX.fieldY)` - but this is applicable only when `fieldY` in `tableX` is defined as UNIQUE.

Comment: count(articles_likes.id) is this a typo - the invoked table is called article_likes? AND id is referred to as article_id in the join?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55825/count-records-in-a-related-table

Answer (score 0):

Your joins are combining every like of an article with every dislike of the same article. As a result you get the product of the two counts. So if an article has 3 likes and 2 dislikes, the joins will generate 6 rows and you get 6 as result for both counts. You could workaround with `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)`, but if you have alot of likes and dislikes, you might also get performance issues. So you should avoid these joins and either preaggregate in subqueries in FROM clause, or use correlated subqueries in SELECT clause like here:

```
select
  articles.id,
  articles.userid,
  articles.article, 
  (
    select count(*)
    from article_likes
    where article_likes.article_id = articles.id
  ) as likes_count,
  (
    select count(*)
    from article_dislikes
    where article_dislikes.article_id = articles.id
  ) as dislikes_count
from articles
```

Comment: @Strawberry Do you have test data for me? If you've found an error, why don't you just tell, so I can fix that. Was it just that one trailing comma?

Comment: Yep - I don't have any test data, so I can't comment on other errors.

Comment: Paul Spiegal thanks man..this one helped me. First itself i should have gone with  sub queries instead of using joins.